# “Go to Definition” in VSCode still shows old Julia version after updating

Tags: julia, vscode-extensions

I recently updated Julia from version 1.8.5 to 1.9.0 and deleted the old version. However, when I use the "Go to Definition" feature in VSCode, it still takes me to the [old version (1.8.5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8vUv.png). Same problem also applies with documentation.

I'm running vscode at Julia v1.9 environment, and the executable path is set to 1.9

I tried re-indexing the language server cache but it didn't work. Other than this issue, the language server seems to be working without any problems.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could help you, but I just updated to 1.9, set the julia environment path to 1.9, and it keeps using 1.8.3.

I tried restarting VScode, to no avail.

Even weirder: I lauched Julia 1.9 from the terminal (I had deal with MacOS security stuff), typed "using StatsBase".  Julia 1.9 then downloaded StatsBase, and Julia created a new "v1.9" environment.

I launched VScode, and it said it could not launch a new Julia session.  Since 1.9 was running in the terminal, I quit 1.9, and restarted VScode.

VScode still couldn't find Julia, so I manually type "./Applications/Julia-1.9.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia" into the VScode terminal.  When I try to run my code, I now get "Could not run editor content in new process" as well as "Could not start the Julia language server. Make sure the 'julia.executablePath' setting is valid."   So, that didn't work.

Here is my Julia executable path in VScode: "/Applications/Julia-1.9.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia"

**Update**

I ended up deleting the ".Julia" folder and relaunching Julia (after I updated the symlink in .usr/bin to point to the 1.9 executable path).  Now everything seems to work fine.